# Using Neyman Pearson lemma on a two sample test for normal means

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, neyman-pearson-lemma

Say I have two groups. I collect $n$ data points from the first ($A$) group ($x_i$) and $m$ data points from the second ($B$) group ($y_j$). The null hypothesis is that the means of the two groups are the same.

$$H_0: \mu_B = \mu_A$$
$$=> \mu_B-\mu_A=0$$
The alternate hypothesis is that the mean of group $B$ is larger than the mean of group $A$ by some effect size, $e$.
$$H_1: \mu_B=\mu_A+e$$
$$=>\mu_B-\mu_A=e$$

I'll assume that the variances of the two groups are the same. I want to use the Neyman Pearson lemma to show that the test statistic that will yield the most power is the one used in the two-sample t-test (or the Wald test). I've been unable to do this and wanted to see if someone can help.

---

My attempt:

In a similar theme to the example provided in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neyman%E2%80%93Pearson_lemma), I first construct the likelihood function:

$$L(\mu_B, \mu_A | x_i, y_j) \propto \exp\left( -\sum_i(x_i-\mu_A)^2 - \sum_j(y_j-\mu_B)^2\right)$$
$$\propto \exp\left(-\left(\sum x_i^2 + \sum y_j^2\right)-2\left(\mu_A \sum x_i+\mu_B\sum y_j\right) +(\mu_A^2+\mu_B^2)\right)$$

Now it seems like when I take the likelihood ratio for the two hypotheses, everything will cancel and the ratio will depend only on $\sum y_j$. This is obviously not right. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: The likelihood is a function of $(\mu_A,\mu_B)$ not $\mu_a-\mu_B$.

Comment: Makes sense, updated.

Comment: The common (unknown) variance must make an appearance in the formulas for the likelihood.

Comment: Instead of parameterizing the model in terms of $\mu_A$ and $\mu_B$ can you parameterize it in terms of $\mu_A$ and $\theta$ where $\theta\equiv\mu_B-\mu_A$?

Comment: Everything cancels if one uses the same parameter values top and bottom. You have to use different parameters top and bottom, eg $(\mu_B, \mu_A)$ and $(\mu_B^\prime, \mu_A^\prime)$. And maximise top and bottom separately under both hypotheses (for [the generalised likelihood ratio test, not Neyman-Pearson](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/512936/7224)).

Comment: @Xi'an - what's wrong with using the Neyman Pearson lemma in this way?